# If a man rubs his penis against a woman's vagina when both are naked, is it zina?

Tags: zina

What if a male rubs his penis against a female's vagina when both are naked, but without insertion. Did Zina happen?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. I strongly recommend you to take our [tour] and visit our [help] to learn more about our site and the stack exchange model!

Comment: Yes. There are many forms of Zina. The major Zina [for which Allah (ﷻ) prescribed a Hadd punishment] is full blown penetration of the female's privates by the man's privates. On the other hand, the lesser Zina is anything short of penetration/insertion but still leads to major Zina [eg, the act you described. Zina of the eyes, limbs, etc].

Answer (score 1):

In addition the unrelated man and woman shouldn't have got to know each other to be alone in the first place as Satan is the third person. And they shouldn't be exposing the 'awrah to each other (uncovering). This is before physically touching wherever.

So if we list:
1.shouldn't be in contact with each other to get to know each other;
2.shouldn't be alone as "Satan is the third".
3.shouldn't be uncovering their body;
4.shouldn't be physically touching.

You can see how one thing leads to another to the ultimate sin of inter course outside wedlock.